# Pre-booking discount SNCF fares without discount card

Tags: sncf

On the SNCF website, discount train fares can be booked without a discount card (e.g., the Carte Jeune). Is it possible to pre-book those fares and then purchase a card at a later time, before the trip, or is it required that the card have been purchased first?

Comment: Beware: SNCF have changed their discount cards recently, and even though you can still buy fares based on the “old”cards, you can no longer buy those cards. It’s probably a good idea to buy both at the same time.

Comment: Although I can't find an explicit reference (therefore the comment), I would think that you need to have a valid discount card at the time of traveling, not at the time of booking.

Answer (score 3):

You can, as long as you keep in mind jcaron's comment, that is buy a ticket for a kind of card that is sold atm.

But you can also buy right now a card with a starting date in the future, which could be the best option.